# How to generate call graph for ROS code?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, I want to analysis roscpp call graph.

Which tools I can use? How?

It will very great if it has graphical interface.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31278/how-to-generate-call-graph-for-ros-code?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2012-04-05**:
Can you use doxygen or codeviz?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-05**:
Thank you. I found that I can use doxywizard to generate each function's call graph,but where is the whole picture call graph? Another question is codeviz should patch compiler,so it seems very hard to work on ROS. How to do it?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-05**:
I also found that doxywizard just generate partial call graph. Because I found that the function it generate call graph failed (roscpp init.cpp init() ). Is there any tool can generate complete call graph? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As with any binary in Linux, you can use [valgrind / callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) to collect the information during run time. A visualizer for the results is e.g. [http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Documentation.html](http://KCachegrind).

You can install the package in Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind kcachegrind
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't really a ROS-specific question, but Stack Overflow has [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373714/generate-calling-graph-for-c-code) which might be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1